# Python: maximization of function

Tags: python, function, pandas, optimization, scipy

Suppose I have the following simple function and inputs:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20170101',periods=20)
a1 = np.ones(3)
b1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(20,3)),index=dates,columns=['foo','bar','see'])
def test_func(a,b):
        c = (a*b).sum(axis=1)
        d = c.std()*np.sqrt(3)
        e = c.mean()/d
        return -np.array(e)
```

I would like to solve this function for a that minimizes the output (maximizes e).

```
scipy.optimize.fmin(test_func,a1,args=(b1))
```

But this throws a type error

```
TypeError: test_func() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

My quesiton is i) is this a good way to solve for the max of such a function and ii) what the devil is the problem?

Comment: the second part is clear. you are misusing the test_func. check [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html). you are providing extra inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the `b1` in the extra argument:

```
scipy.optimize.fmin(test_func,a1,args=(b1,))
```

seems to work.

Comment: Brilliant! This is helpful.  So to be clear, the 'args' parameter requires a trailing comma with 1, but not 2, variables?  For other functions that require more inputs, I've used 'args=(b1,c1,d1)' and it's worked just fine.

Comment: That is correct: `(b1,)` is a tuple with one element, while `(b1)` is just `b1` itself. From the the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences): "A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective."